# Left and right triggers for xbox elite controller 2 not working on android

Tags: controllers, xbox-one, android

I have a galaxy note 9 plus. A new elite controller series 2. I have connected the controller through Bluetooth. Loaded into fortnite. The game accepts the controller and gives me options to configure the controller. I load into a match. I can not aim nor shoot. I downloaded gamepad mapper apps. Which all display lt and rt as throttle and brake keys. Basically they do not seem to be recognized as buttons for shooter games, but rather as throttle and brakes for racing games. I then went to a site for android developers where they are working on updating elite controllers and regular xbox controllers keymapping with the left and right triggers set as buttons instead of an axis. Yet there is nowhere to download the files to my phone. Basically I have zero knowledge with android systems as far as where files are located, how to access them and reconfigure them or else I would have tried to change the values myself. Can anyone help me with this.

Side note: I am 70 percent sure I saw on Microsoft and Fortnites websites that the Elite Series 2 would work for android fortnite and is supported. Yet the left and Right triggers do not work.

Comment: What version of android are you running?

Answer (score -2):

You might try  buying a whole new remote. You could also try to use the a b x y buttons instead.